# My css styling cannot be found when ran locally

Tags: html, css, django

I am trying to link my html to the corresponding css styling in file style.css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Both the html file and the css file are in the same folder, however, if I launch my server and show the web page I keep getting this error:

`Not Found: /style.css "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2272`

Opening the file from the file directory as a web page, it works fine. It only gets this error when I try launch the server page using django framework.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Check the case of "style.css" file name, unix system is case sensitive to file names, maybe here is the problem.

Comment: Follow the tutorial in the Django docs corresponding the specific version of Django you're using.  Here's the part that describes how to set up your static files https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial06/ with version 4.1.